# Preg_replace Pattern Issue

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to highlight the exact term in $vQuery, currently it will highlight the whole word if $vQuery is part of a word. I can't use str_replace or str_ireplace due to case issues between what needs to be displayed and what the replace does, so I'm left with an over complicated statement using preg_replace.

```
 preg_replace("/\b".$vQuery."\b/i", "<span class=\"highlightedTerm\">$0</span>", $vName);
```

The above statement will match as it's intended to but say I search for `car` it will highlight all words `car` but it will also highlight anything that contains `car`.

Is there an easy way to modify the pattern to make it an exact match?!

**EDIT:**

Say I have:

```
 This is the carpet in my car.
```

I'm looking to have an output like:

```
 This is the <span class="highlightedTerm">car</div>pet in my <span class="highlightedTerm">car</div>.
```

Currently, what I'm getting is:

```
 This is the <span class="highlightedTerm">carpet</div> in my <span class="highlightedTerm">car</div>.
```

Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: It should match only the "whole word" car since you use the word boundry: http://regex101.com/r/jU1vV9

Comment: I've updated the question with more information to make my question clearer.

Comment: Ditch the `\b`s http://regex101.com/r/hZ4zB6 A good tip would be to do a regex tutorial to learn what the meta charachters, anchors and so on mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @jurgemaister I was able to figure it out and below is the pattern that works for my case.

```
 preg_replace("/".$this->mQuery."/i", "<span class=\"highlightedTerm\">$0</span>", $vName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Include a space at the end and at the beginning of the term. This way you only catch ' car ' and not 'cartoon'. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

strange because the word boundary should have done the trick .. i.e.

```
/\bHello\b/
```

You may also try it without the word boundary at the beginning since the string may be only one word.

```
/Hello\b/
```

you could also make the search case insensitive

```
/\bHello\b/i
```

IF there are special characters in the words causing issues you can have them display as utf-8 just in case

```
/\bHello\b/u
```

or all of the above

```
/Hello\b/iu
```